# TypeORM - QueryFailedError: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I am building an application using NestJS and a MySQL database. I am getting this error without any proper indicaton in the error log where this comes from (in code) and I could not resolve this issue myself as I don't have much database background knowledge besides building crud apps.

Any idea what I have to do or where to look in order to fix this error?

"QueryFailedError: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

There was no change on the code base before this error was thrown, yesterday it all worked fine and from today on it keeps crashing after a few minutes of runtime.